# IDE with Kconfig support?

Tags: eclipse, linux-kernel, eclipse-plugin, kbuild

Is there any IDE that exports Kconfig files to automatically add include and source folders, as well as setting the actual symbols that are defined there?

I mean, it's next to impossible to have a complete Eclipse environment for Linux Kernel development. Right now I basically have a "Makefile Project" with chosen include and source folders and built in build, but my code is dependent on symbols defined in kernel build.

**EDIT**

I just realized that kernel build generates a include/generated/autoconf.h, which is a great help in this and probably enough for most of the developers

Comment: For VS-Code + vscode-cpptools extension, you can use the `"forcedInclude"` setting in the c_cpp_properties.json:
`"forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/include/generated/autoconf.h"]`

Answer (score 0):

There's a KDevelop plugin called kdev-kernel: https://github.com/Gnurou/kdev-kernel . It was an improvement over loading the kernel as a "generic makefile project" but isn't a complete solution.

It seemed to ignore some .config options, and it only works with specific versions of KDevelop. I'm not sure which ones, as I use Gentoo and usually compile a -9999 version of KDevelop (in Gentoo, -9999 indicates the head of some revision control branch... so the version depends on when I compiled).

In spite of the drawbacks, it might be worth trying or building upon; I find KDevelop's "intellisense" very useful.